# using preg_match to match one string followed by another

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm working on seeing if a particular database has certain grants given to it in a script. In the following case:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `bar`.* TO 'foo'@'localhost'
```

Is there a `preg_match` string that can check that `grant all` is followed by the name of a database, in this case `bar` and return true if yes otherwise false?

Comment: do you want a regex that extract database name from your string ?

Comment: no, I just want to check if a database has grant all privileges, that requires parsing the string above

Comment: Use https://regex101.com/ to test your regex.

Comment: This sounds as if you just wanted ``if (strpos($s, 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `bar`') !== false)``

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code to find all string thaht start with `GRANT ALL` and then followed by any characters

you can see result and test your string from http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/dFh

```
<?php
preg_match_all("/GRANT\sALL.*/", $input_lines, $output_array);


if(count($output_array)>0){

}else{

}

?>
```